# Where can I find Orient Expedition 7419 gameboard tiles to print?

Tags: lego-games, printing

I lost the cardboard gameboard squares.
Does anybody have a high quality scan of the tiles so I can print them ?

Comment: You are asking us to help you commit a copyright violation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can buy missing items on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=7419-1&viewItemType=G).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you refer to parts [4189445pb01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=4189445pb01) through [4189445pb11](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=4189445pb11), all pieces of ["gear" from set 7419](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=7419-1&viewItemType=G).

The low-resolution scans available from the BrickLink item descriptions might be enough, though they will require some labour on your part. You can also consider buying second-hand tiles from BrickLink vendors. I don't think there are publicly-available high-resolution scans.

Otherwise, do try contacting LEGO support; they might be able to help with a replacement.

Comment: Highly unlikely that LEGO will able to help with unique replacement parts for 19 year old set.

Comment: Somebody might have some printable files tucked away in a drawer, and asking has zero risk of anything.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer @IvanSanchez.